# How much info does onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) save?

Tags: java, android

I read that the transaction buffer has a limit which is **1MB**, if I exceed it, I will get an **TransactionTooLargeException**. I´d like to know if the bundle stored in **onSaveInstanceState method** is sharing this 1MB or not?. If not, how much info I can save there?.

I know that I can use a **Retained Fragment** to save complex data, but I´m really interested to know the answer of that question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I´d like to know if the bundle stored in onSaveInstanceState method is sharing this 1MB or not?.

Yes. Across all simultaneous IPC transactions, you cannot have more than 1MB of data. For that reason, and for overall device performance, please keep your saved instance state `Bundle` *small*. For example, do not put a `Customer` object in the `Bundle`; put an identifier that allows you to retrieve the `Customer` (from an in-memory cache where possible, or else from the backing store).